# How to downgrade Laravel version 5.8 to 5.1 in Ubuntu server?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

```
"name": "laravel/laravel",
 "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
 "keywords": [
     "framework",
     "laravel"
 ],
 "license": "MIT",
 "type": "project",
 "require": {
     "php": ">=5.5.9",
     "laravel/framework": "^5.8.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply update the `composer.json` so that it looks like this `"require":"{..., "laravel/framework":"5.1.*"` then run `composer update`. 
 You may want to downgrade some other dependencies too, if the command fails (it will show you where the problem is, though).

Note: It is NOT recommended to run `composer update` on production server. You may want to do it on your local machine, and after pushing the code to production, run `composer install` there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure downgrading to lower levels is a possibility with Laravel. 
The best alternative will be to install a fresh Laravel 5.1 and move your code to it like your controllers and route configurations. 
You can install a fresh Laravel 5.1 with 
`composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.1.*"` [Laravel 5.1 installation guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation)

Good luck.